# WooCommerce category and zone specific service fee

Tags: woocommerce

I found this snippet for WooCommerce to add a service fee.

```
    // Add Service Fee to Category
function woo_add_cart_fee() {

$category_ID = '23';
global $woocommerce;

foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {
    // Get the terms, i.e. category list using the ID of the product
$terms = get_the_terms( $values['product_id'], 'product_cat' );
    // Because a product can have multiple categories, we need to iterate through the list of the products category for a match
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        // 23 is the ID of the category for which we want to remove the payment gateway
        if($term->term_id == $category_ID){
         $excost = 6;
         }
         }
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee('Service Fee', $excost, $taxable = false, $tax_class = '');
}
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee' );
```

How can I add service fee to certain zones only?

And how can this be ignored, if cart amount is over $250

Comment: $woocommerce->customer->get_country() and WC_Cart::get_cart_total();

Comment: Yes, those might be the hooks, but not a snippet really.

Comment: check this for a start https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916432/woocommerce-get-current-shipping-zone